# Implementing XOR linked list. Size 1 or 2

Tags: c, linked-list, xor-linkedlist

Suppose this is my XOR linked list struct...

```
struct xList {
    int data;
    xList* xor;
}
```

What should `xor` contain if the **size of the xor linked list is 1 or 2**?

Comment: Address of head and tail (resp, NULL)?

Comment: Address of the next node in the list? Or `NULL` for the last node? What else should it contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What should xor contain if the size of the xor linked list is 1 or 2?

It should contain `prev ^ next` where `prev` is a pointer to the previous element, `next` is a pointer to the next element, and `^` is the XOR operator. The first element in the list obviously has `nil` for the previous item, and the last item has `nil` for the last item, so you'd get `nil ^ next` and `prev ^ nil` for those elements, respectively. In a list of size 1, there's no previous *or* next element, so you can probably figure out what you'd store in the `xor` field.

The idea with an xor linked list is that you have to know the address of either the previous or next element in the list already in order to determine the next or previous element. That's no problem if you're iterating through the list, though, and since that's what you *do* with linked lists, it can be a useful optimization. If you're iterating from head to tail, for example, you start with a pointer to the first element in the list. The previous element is `nil`, so to get the next element you compute: `next = prev ^ xor`. You also have to remember the pointer to the current element before moving to the next element, so that you can use it to get to the following element.

Answer (score 0):

You store (previous ^ next) in the xorlink pointer.

Consider

```
struct xList 
{
    int data;
    xList* xorlink;
}
```

A -> B -> C -> D

You start from the head. You know head doesn't have a previous - so xorlink will point to the B node. You save the current pointer(A) and move to next (B). 
You do (A ^ B->xorlink) to get the pointer to C. (B ^ C->xorlink) will give you the pointer to D. And so on

Reverse traversal is also similar.

Anyway, the answer to your question

1. If the size is 1, then the first node's xorlink should contain NULL.
2. If the size is 2, then the first node's xorlink should contain a pointer to 2nd node. The 2nd node's xorlink should contain a pointer to the 1st node.